# notification popup with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've tried to create some notification message that should showing up anytime i have a new message. is done but the problem is if i refresh the browser then the message showing again. this is wrong. it should be hidden if already shows. does not matter if i refresh the browser again. it should be not show.

this is my code:

```
$(function(){
/* global MessageBus */
var name,
    msgCube = $('.message_bus').data('queue') ;

   MessageBus.ajax = function(args){
     args["headers"]["X-NAME"] = name;
     return $.ajax(args);
   };

    MessageBus.subscribe("/tasks" + msgCube, function(msg){

        var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);

        showMsg = function(){

            var deffered = $.Deferred();

            if(obj.state.viewed == 0){

                dataModel = '<div class="msg">'
                + '<p>' + obj.task.name + '</p>'
                +'<p>' + obj.task.description + '</p>';

                $('.noticed').html(dataModel);
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".noticed").fadeOut(300);
                    deffered.resolve();
                }, 5000);
            }
            return deffered.promise();
        };

        //test don't show up after load
        stopToLoad = function(){

            console.log('load after');

            $('.noticed').hide();

        };

        showMsg().then(function(){
            stopToLoad();
        });


        //console.log(msg);



    }, 0);

});
```

if you guys have an any sugestion, any solution, idea, i'll be glad and thanks for the Adviced.

best regard,

Comment: Are you using cookies or session? 
If session: you can add an extra value the time of the session. 
If cookie, you can set a new cookie/update one by adding this extra parameter and test it afterwards.

Comment: @Lio_69 thank you so much for the suggestion. yes i've tried with the cookies before that. but unfortunatelly the message will shut down like forever and wont show up again :). event if i get a new message, the notification will not showing becouse i have a cookie behind that :) is not working like it should.